# UITableViewCell square rectangle style

Tags: objective-c

Hi I would like to get the following style for my UITableViewCell.

Here is a sample:

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of setting the cell's `backgroundView`, as I do here:

[image]

The differences between that and what you show in your screen shot are purely matters of cosmetic detail: in your screen shot, there is no gray gradient but rather a white rounded rectangle, the white rounded rectangle is drawn with a shadow, the cell height is taller, and the background view image is deliberately made shorter than the cell height so as to increase the apparent spacing between cells. But those are trivial matters of drawing and configuration.

Comment: You can do it without setting a background, see my answer below.

Comment: @matt I just add a backgroundview to my cell and set the view backgroundcolor to green so I can see it, but even if I make smaller the frame of my view it fits all the with of the row. Any clue?

Comment: The background view _itself_ is automatically resized to the size of the cell no matter what. You need to give that view a subview which is sized smaller relative to its superview. Or, make it an image view and use a smaller image in Center mode. That is why I said in my answer that you make the background view _image_ smaller - you can't make the background view _itself_ smaller.

Answer (score 0):

First add a `bacgroundImage` to your `controller` and then just make `UITableViewCell`'s background clear color and in your `CustomViewCell` add a `UIView` with white `backgroundColor`. Adjust your `UITableViewSeperatorStyle` to none. Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

For background view you should use:

```
self.myTableView.backgroundView = bgView;
```

Then you should change height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Just put an int value here, it represent height of your cell.

For text i recommend you to place `UILabel` on your cell, and then change its properties to customize font, size of text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cell` is your table view cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReuseIdentifier"];

    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    // or whatever you want to set your corner radius

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple. When designing your custom cell create add a UIView to it that is inset on all sides. Similar to this.

[image]

Then create a property for the UIView like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *cellInsetView;
```

Make sure you hook this up in Interface Builder.

Then inside your view controller ViewDidLoad method you can add the following to create the rounded corners and a shadow line underneath. (I recommend creating a method that builds your custom view to keep your ViewDidLoad method cleaner.)

```
//Set the corner radius and alpha to cell background
    self.cellInsetView.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
    self.cellInsetView.layer.masksToBounds = YES; //Corner Radius
    [self.cellInsetView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.35]];

//create bottom shadow/border
    CALayer *cellInsetBottomShadow = [CALayer layer];

//Place the border according to the cell size    
    cellInsetBottomShadow.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.cellInsetView.frame.size.height-1.0f, self.cellInsetView.frame.size.width-2.0f, 1.0f);

    cellInsetBottomShadow.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3].CGColor;

//Add the bottom border/shadow to the cell
    [self.cellInsetView.layer addSublayer:cellInsetBottomShadow];
```

The above code will produce a cell similar to the one shown below, you can modify the corner radius to get your desired effect. I have an alpha set on the background of the cells in which you may not desire.

[image]